# Ruby Determine Season (Fall, Winter, Spring or Summer)

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am working on a script that is supposed to determine the "season" of the year based on date ranges:

For Example:

```
January 1 - April 1: Winter
April 2 - June 30: Spring
July 1 - September 31: Summer
October 1 - December 31: Fall
```

I am not sure how the best way (or the best ruby way) to go about doing this. Anyone else run across how to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you also take into account whether the script is ran in the northern or southern hemisphere?

Comment: This is a cron job that will run on one of my servers, so I know where it will be ran

Comment: Most places define summer as the 3 hottest months and winter the 3 coldest. If you're running it from where your profile says you are, then you'd want to shift it 1 month to the left.

Comment: Your dates are not official seasons and the way you have them is easier than the real seasons where winter will start in December and end in March. This is where I'm getting hung up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

31 September?

As leifg suggested, here it is in code:

```
require 'Date'

class Date

  def season
    # Not sure if there's a neater expression. yday is out due to leap years
    day_hash = month * 100 + mday
    case day_hash
      when 101..401 then :winter
      when 402..630 then :spring
      when 701..930 then :summer
      when 1001..1231 then :fall
    end
  end
end
```

Once defined, call it e.g. like this:

```
d = Date.today
d.season
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! I have been toying with this all morning long.. thanks so much!

Comment: better use `month*100 + mday`, will be 10x faster

Comment: @zed_0xff: Yes, in fact I measured it as 200x faster on Ruby 1.9.3, so I'm updating the answer. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for the actual seasons (December 21 - March 20 as winter, for example). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Corey: Change the numbers in the case block to match whatever definitions you wish to use. The values in this answer match the season definitions in the question.

Comment: @NeilSlater but it doesn't work to say like `1221..321`

Comment: @Corey So have five cases - the first and last will both result in Winter

Answer (score 2):

You could try with ranges and Date objects:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_ranges.htm

Answer (score 1):

without ranges.

```
  require 'date'

    def season
      year_day = Date.today.yday().to_i
      year = Date.today.year.to_i
      is_leap_year = year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0
      if is_leap_year and year_day > 60
        # if is leap year and date > 28 february 
        year_day = year_day - 1
      end

      if year_day >= 355 or year_day < 81
        result = :winter
      elsif year_day >= 81 and year_day < 173
        result = :spring
      elsif year_day >= 173 and year_day < 266
        result = :summer
      elsif year_day >= 266 and year_day < 355
       result = :autumn
      end

      return result
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Neil Slater's answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15416170/210980) approach is great but for me those dates aren't quite correct. They show fall ending on December 31st which isn't the case in any scenario I can think of.

Using the [northern meteorological](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/aboutseasons.html) seasons:

> - Spring runs from March 1 to May 31;
> - Summer runs from June 1 to August 31;
> - Fall (autumn) runs from September 1 to November 30; and
> - Winter runs from December 1 to February 28 (February 29 in a leap year).

The code would need to be updated to:

```
require "date"

class Date
  def season
    day_hash = month * 100 + mday
    case day_hash
      when 101..300 then :winter
      when 301..531 then :spring
      when 601..831 then :summer
      when 901..1130 then :fall
      when 1201..1231 then :winter
    end
  end
end
```