# Getting number of events within a season based on date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Event with a datetime column set by the user.

I'm trying to get a total number of events in each season (spring, summer, fall, winter).

I'm trying with something like:

```
Event.where('extract(month from event_date) >= ? AND extract(day from event_date) >= ? AND extract(month from event_date) < ? AND extract(day from event_date) < ?', 6, 21, 9, 21).count
```

The example above would return the number of events in the Summer, for example (at least in the northern hemisphere).

It doesn't seem like my example above is working, i'm getting no events returned even though there are events in that range. I think my order of operations (ands) may be messing with it. Any idea of the best method to get what I need?

**Edit**: actually looking at this more this will not work at all. Is there anyway select dates within a range without the year?

**Edit 2**: I'm trying to somehow use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414831/ruby-determine-season-fall-winter-spring-or-summer/15416170?noredirect=1#comment120063864_15416170) to help me out, but this is Ruby and not SQL.

```
require 'date'

class Date

  def season
    day_hash = month * 100 + mday
    case day_hash
      when 101..320 then :winter
      when 321..620 then :spring
      when 621..920 then :summer
      when 921..1220 then :fall
      when 1221..1231 then :winter
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the query Rails generated? This looks like it should work actually

Comment: It doesn't work. It's looking for a day between 21 and 21.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field

Comment: @sig that's what I based my attempt off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

in `lib` created a file called `season.rb`

```
require 'date'

class Date

  def season
    day_hash = month * 100 + mday
    case day_hash
      when 101..320 then :winter
      when 321..620 then :spring
      when 621..920 then :summer
      when 921..1220 then :fall
      when 1221..1231 then :winter
    end
  end
end
```

in `lib` created a file called `count_by.rb`:

```
module Enumerable
  def count_by(&block)
    list = group_by(&block)
      .map { |key, items| [key, items.count] }
      .sort_by(&:last)
      
    Hash[list]
  end
end
```

Now I can get the season for any date, as well as use `count_by` on the model.

So then ultimately I can run:

`Event.all.count_by { |r| r.event_date.season }[:spring]`

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the month and day and query everything in between.
e.g 621..921

In SQL it would be something like

```
SUMMER_START = 621
SUMMER_END = 921
Event.where("concat(extract(month from event_date), extract(day from event_date)) > ? AND concat(extract(month from event_date), extract(day from event_date)") < ?,
 SUMMER_START, SUMMER_END)
```

This can be easily made into a scope method that accepts a season (e.g 'winter'), takes the appropriate season start and end and returns the result.